# How to create a required module directory structure in Python using pyproject.toml / setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

My current project structure is as follows:

```
project
  mod1
  mod2
  mod3
  pyproject.toml
  admin.py
```

I would like to come up with pyproject.toml in such a way that after doing a pip install . or installing the wheel file, user will see this

```
ls -la build/lib/
project
    mod1
    mod2
    admin.py
```

And anyone who installs the wheel file will be able to use the module like this

```
python3 -m project.admin
```

I am able to solve this using a src/ based folder structure but is there anyway that I can get this to work with the current folder structure ?